# Plotting Separated plots with GGPLOT in R using for Loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

`d` is my dataframe:

```
set.seed(0)
date<-seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/1/10"), by = "days")
x <- c(rep(1:10, 2,5)+rnorm(20)/4, rep(6:15, 2,5) + rnorm(20)/5)
y <- c(rep(1:10, 2)+rnorm(20)/5, rep(6:15, 2) + rnorm(20)/5)
replicate <- gl(4, 10, 40)
d <- data.frame(replicate=replicate,date=date,y=y,x=x)
```

I want to plot y and x on the same plot using dataframe inside a for loop. The X-axis will be the `date` column. As I only have 4 different groups (replicate is the index group), I will have to have 4 plots, with the X-axis being the date column, as I mentioned before. I´ve been trying to do this, but its not working:

```
for (var in unique(d$replicate)) {
  dev.new()
  print(ggplot(d[d$replicate==var,],aes(date=date, y=y, colour=replicate)) + geom_line())
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Try replacing `date=date` with `x=date` in your `aes()` mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your `aes()` call the first argument should be named `x` not `date` so the call becomes : `aes(x=date, y=y, colour=replicate))`. The code should the work.

However, to plot both x and y on the same plot having date as the x axis, you need to do the following:

```
for (i in unique(d$replicate)){
  dev.new()
  p <- ggplot(filter(d, replicate == i),
              aes(date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y, colour = "blue")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x, colour = "red"))
  print(p)
}
```